# Wired IEEE 802.1x for windows

Tags: c++, windows, security, lan, radius

Does anybody know Windows API function (or other ways) for Windows 7/8/10 for **wired**(lan, not wifi) adapters which allow to:

1. Enable and configure 802.1x authentication for **wired** adapter
2. Most important - set credentials(user+password or certificate) which to use for 802.1x authentication for **wired** adapter

All what I found is that 802.1x can be configured with command line but without specifying credentials

**netsh lan** (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732869(v=ws.10).aspx)

*With **wireless** adapters everything works fine using Native Wifi functions:*

*WlanSetProfile – create profile*

*WlanSetProfileEapXmlUserData – set credentials*

Comment: Struggling to find the solutions too!